# Tagging translate content with Google Translator

Tags: google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I know that there is tag to identify content to be skipped for translation or even to skip an entire page. But I am actually looking the other way around. Is there a tag to use to identify only the content that needs translation?

Comment: I havent used the translator API, but you can probably achieve this using basic set theory. Create a set of things to be skipped. Simply remove that from the universal set (set of all content). You'll have a set of all the non-skipped items/items to be translated.

Comment: Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Google Website Translator or Translate API?

For Translate API doing affirmative "selection-only" translation, simply provide only the text you want translated to the [API call](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text) and only that will be translated.

As for the website translator, you are basically telling Google "please translate this entire site" as a premise, so everything is by default translated UNLESS you [tell it not to](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions).